# Visual Studio's C# automated event handlers generation. Why does it create a new delegate?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

When I write `_exporter.csvRowProcessed +=`, Visual Studio 2010 offers me to create a method to handle said event, and then proceeds to do this:
`_exporter.csvRowProcessed += new CsvRowProcessedHandler(RowProcessedHandler);`

What I wanted to know is, why does it create a new delegate and then assigns it a handler method, instead of just assigning the handler method directly to the event like this?

```
exporter.csvRowProcessed += RowProcessedHandler;
```

Here is the whole code just in case.

```
    private void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        object[][] data = _grid.AsMatrix();
        _exporter.csvRowProcessed += new CsvRowProcessedHandler(RowProcessedHandler);
        string csv = _exporter.CreateCSVString(data);

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(_path, false);
        writer.Write(csv);
        writer.Close();
    }

    void RowProcessedHandler(object o, int currentRow)
    {
        radProgressBarElement.Text = "Procesando linea " + currentRow;
        radProgressBarElement.Value1 = currentRow;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Resharper or any tools?

Comment: I'm using the Productivity Power Tools extension, but as far as I know that feature is native to Visual Studio.

Comment: It's not clear what your edit part means. It would be *very* odd IMO for it to complete what you'd already typed by introducing a new local variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both forms create a new delegate *instance*. They're equivalent in the generated code, as far as I'm aware.

While I prefer the method group conversion too, I suspect this wasn't (before VS 2012, as noted in the comment) changed simply because there wasn't enough benefit from doing so. Indeed, some people may even prefer the more explicit form which shows the type of the delegate being created.

Comment: Thanks. I thought maybe I was missing something about delegates and events handling.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 is using the method group conversion: http://www.schwammysays.net/visual-studio-2012-tip-better-event-handler-code-completion/ - looks like they decided it was worthwhile after all.